# How do I make a fiery particle system?

Tags: unity

I added a particle system to the flame-emitting object in my Unity scene. But it's just little white balls, and I can't figure out how to make it fiery.

Anyone?

Everything I see on the internet involves buying some asset pack that somebody put together. Does Unity really not have any built in flames stuff?

Comment: Unity has a fire particle system package that comes with it. Play around with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has a built-in fire particle effect package.  Just [import the 'Particles' standard asset package](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-InstallStandardAssets.html).  It will include small and large flames (and they even have a smoke element to them).  You can toy with that to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fire is colored like this:

HOTTER ---------------> WARMER

BLUE -> WHITE -> ORANGE -> RED

Have you tried to change the particle color over time?
Maybe start with orange to red and fade the alpha over time.

Comment: But then it's just a bunch of orangey squares/circles. How do you make more realistic fire?

Comment: There are some examples here:
http://beta.unity3d.com/3.5-preview/ShurikenExamples.zip

Answer (score 0):

Unity preinstalled assets arent too great to see but they are just as exemple!

If you'd like to make more realistic fire emitter i suggest you to search in assets store, and also I'm not so sure that the particle emitter would be the better choise for you.

I suggest you to use an Halo like base for your flame (a very little halo could give a great visual support) an than use a third part program to make the fire, Unity isnt the best tool for doing graphical stuffs. :)

You can check this, maybe it can help: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/2875-Smokey

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So look at the menu in the inspector that says Particle system. Scroll down and click renderer. click on material then search for the fire particle. **SORRY FOR SO LATE ANSWER**

Comment: Your name is late answer, you answered late, and you apologized for the late answer.  So...ok.  The real problem is you didn't add anything that hasn't been addressed in other answers already.

Comment: Is this real life?